# instance member of 'currentDevice' cannot be used on type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, orientation, device-orientation

I'm making a video player for IOS & want to check when the device is rotated, when it is my code will make the video player fullscreen, but on I'm getting the following error - 'Instance member 'currentDevice' cannot be used on type 'viewController'

```
var currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation //error here

if orientation.isLandscape {

}

if orientation.isPortrait {

}
```

I've tried to replace currentDevice with a multiple of things, I've also tried to put `_` under it and also `self.`I've started working with Swift a couple of days ago, is there anyone who could point me in the right direction please?

[I've found the code here.](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/155475/iOS---Get-device-orientation-in-Swift)

Comment: where do you put the posted code in your viewcontroller class?

Comment: put the code in viewDidLoad() or in function.

Comment: the variables above my viewDiDLoad(); function

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem! :D

Comment: you cant use currentDevice outside function. you need to use it inside viewDidLoad or other function.

Comment: @BhagyalaxmiPoojary is there a way to keep checking wether or not the device is in landscape or portrait mode?

Comment: you can check in viewWillAppear().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to force the app into landscape mode in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :)

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue{
        print("Device is in Landscape Mode")
} else {
        print(" Device is in Portrait mode ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing and why this is different to improve the answer.